# Where is this alert defined "Alert: Average Server exceptions"?

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

I am receiving this "Average Server Exceptions" email alert and a lot of other people in our organization is receiving them. I was trying to check where is it defined and configure the people that should receive these emails. Is it sent by "Smart Detection" Abnormal rise in exception volume rule?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

In azure portal -> your application insights -> Alerts blade, click the `View classic alerts` button:
[image]

Then in the Alert(classic) page, check the alerts which contains a condition like **Server exceptions > 1 Count**:
[image]

Then click the alert, you can see the details(like set condition, email):
[image]

And the last, this is the email I received:
[image]

---

You can click this blue button `View application in Azure portal` in the email, and it will direct you to where the alert defined.

[image]

Besides that, you can go to azure portal to see where it is defined. Two places:

1.smart detection: in your app insights in portal -> smart detection blade-> settings -> Failure Anomalies, then click it to see the rule details:

[image]

[image]

check the rule details:
[image]

2.Alert: go to portal -> Alerts, check if any rule are there:
[image]

If no rules there, you can click the `View classis Alerts` button, then check if any rules are there. If it has a rule, click it to see details:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for you answer Ivan. My "Smart Detection Settings / Edit Rule" screen looks different, it doesn't have any field, excepting for the "info" field that says "This detection rule automatically ...". Looking in Alerts and Classic Alerts screens, i couldn't find an alert with the name "Average Server Exceptions" mentioned in the email's subject

Comment: Actually, the "Average Server Exceptions" is not the alert name, it's the value of Performance metric. I can reproduce your issue, please refer to the update section in my answer.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you for your investigation. I am able to create the "Server Exceptions" classic alert. However this alert doesn't exist and as a matter of fact the application listed in my email doesn't have any alert or classic alert. Suspecting the Azure Portal UI, I double checked using REST APIs calls: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/alertrules/listbysubscription and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metricalerts/listbysubscription but I still wasn't able to find it. Odd.